# How can I get Internet Explorer 10 or 11 to install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, windows-7

I'm trying to get IE 10 or 11 to install with wine an get stuck with either "Operating system not supported" when wine is set to vista or win 8, or "Internet Explorer needs an update before installing" Win 7. The required update appears to be Windows 7 Service Pack 1. Is there any way I can get the windows 7 in wine to service pack level 1.

I'm no fan of IE or Edge but I have an important needed program (Sabre Red) that apparently has a dependency on Internet Explorer 10 or later in order to run. This is my primary holdup to escape the MS stronghold as my primary production machine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: On irrelevant note, I'd recommend to ask authors of Sabre Red for when they're going to provide GNU/Linux version. Because if nobody asks, this means there's no demand, and nobody would care.